# Leave terminal normal mode

Tags: terminal, normal-mode, terminal-buffer, vim8

Once I'm in 'terminal **normal** mode' (where VIM has control on the terminal display), i can't come back to simple 'terminal mode' (where i can write BASH or launch process).

How to leave the "terminal normal mode" (and be able again to write BASH code or launch process...) ?

Comment: The `Ctrl-\ ` can be tricky on some keyboard layout. Maybe could you test with a mapping `tnoremap <C-q> <C-\><C-n>` and verify that `Ctrl-q` works.

Comment: It didn't solve the problem. I should try with a newer version of VIM.

Comment: Which OS are you usin?. I have verified that with the official 8.1 release, it works well.

Comment: I use Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (extract from lsb_release -a)

Comment: Looking at you solution I have a confusion. There are two terminal modes 1. `Terminal > N` where Vim movements and yank operation can be performed, 2. `Terminal` where terminal command are executed. The `Ctrl-\ Ctrl-n` should make you switch from `Terminal` to `Terminal > N`. The `a` should make you switch from `'Terminal > N` to `Terminal`. Do we have the same understanding? (I have tested on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and vim or gVim 8.1 and it works well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `:help Terminal-Normal`

```
                        *Terminal-Normal* *E946*
In Terminal-Normal mode you can move the cursor around with the usual Vim
commands, Visually mark text, yank text, etc.  But you cannot change the
contents of the buffer.  The commands that would start insert mode, such as
'i' and 'a', return to Terminal-Job mode.  The window will be updated to show
the contents of the terminal. |:startinsert| is ineffective.
```

The command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>\</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>n</kbd> goes to Normal mode from *any* mode (`:help CTRL-\_CTRL-N`), including terminal mode (`:help t_CTRL-\_CTRL-N`). There is also specially

```
    'termwinkey' N         go to terminal Normal mode, see below
    'termwinkey' CTRL-N    same as CTRL-W N |t_CTRL-W_N|
```

where `'termwinkey'` defaults to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd>.

Once in (terminal) Normal mode, to return to using the terminal, press `i`, `a`, `I`, `A`, *etc.* I often press `A`, but it really doesn't matter much except that `:startinsert` doesn't work.

Comment: My question is "how to leave terminal mode". The answer is pressing ```a```. Thanks.

Comment: @floupinette yes, that is why I covered both at the beginning and end of the post :)

Comment: @BenKnoble, I have tried to leave terminal mode using `<Ctrl-w><Ctrl-n>` but it doesn't seems to work on Windows or Unbuntu 22.04 at least.

Comment: I'm using Vim on Windows and Ubuntu 20.04 and on both `Ctrl-w Ctrl-n` do not work for me.

Comment: C-w N works for me (case matters there) but not C-w C-n (with or without shift) (it opens a new window). Could be a bug. @VivianDeSmedt

Comment: We have the same behavior. `Ctrl-w Shift-n` works but `Ctrl-w Ctrl-n` open a new window on top of the terminal. Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 modes :

1. "Terminal" or "Terminal mode" : You can execute bash commands, launch programs
2. "Terminal >N" or "Terminal Normal mode" : VIM has control on the terminal display

To come back from "Terminal Normal mode" to "Terminal mode"....just press `a`

Comment: Hi Floupinette, when you would like to take answer from the comment the recommended behavior is to ask the commenter to post an answer him/her self such that he can get the credit for his answer. If he do not react you should make it a community answer.

Comment: OK. I willl delete within few minutes so. Sorry. You helped me a lot by the way :). Many thanks

Comment: You can keep your answer :-). I just feel responsible to teach the "rules" to newcomers.